# Tomcat needs restart to unpack WARs?

Tags: tomcat, war, unpack, autodeploy

I'm developing webapps in Netbeans.  I generate the WAR file and drop it into the webapps folder under tomcat home. I see it in the manager app automatically, but it doesn't unpack the contents of the WAR file until I restart the Tomcat service. Heres the config in server.xml:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

Am I missing some configuration there to make it unpack WARs by itself? Any help appreciated!

**EDIT**

Also, it's not AutoDeploying.  I see it in the manager app, but I have to manually start it by clicking on the start button.

Comment: Perhaps other configuration is interfering. Try downloading a fresh copy of Tomcat. Do not modify, do not make Your IDE (Netbeans) aware of it. Simply run the fresh Tomcat and drop in the WAR file. Give Tomcat a few minutes, or maybe go to lunch. Shouldn't take that long, but since you are having trouble, try it.

Comment: @Basil I did a fresh install of TC8 and everything works as expected. Unpacks WARs and autodeploys them. Any idea of what might be interfering?

Comment: With [Servlet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html) containers in general, and [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) specifically, configuration is defined in layers in various places. I don't recall details, but a little googling of the "upackWARs" and "autoDeploy" attributes should be revealing. Also, I don't know about [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/), but on Eclipse with [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/), the Tomcat directory is not directly used – instead invisible folders hold your WAR & related files & Tomcat stuff with configuration re-defined on-the-fly.

Comment: I have SPNEGO running on it, could that be it? Also, this tomcat isn't attached to NetBeans, theyre totally independent from each other, I just drop the WARs generated from NB into the webapps folder manually.